# Ionic Slide Tabs Header Spacing is Off

Tags: css, ionic-framework

The spacing between the headers on my tabs when using [`ionic-slide-box-tabs`](https://github.com/JKnorr91/ion-slide-box-tabs) .

It works fine in the browser, but the spacing is off on my android device.

[image]

The markup looks like the following

```
<ion-slide-box  style="position:absolute; bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0; " slide-tabs-scrollable="true" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" class="has-header" show-pager="false" ion-slide-tabs>
                 <ion-slide ion-slide-tab-label="{{category.name}}" ng-repeat="category in model.selectedMenu.categories" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
                     <ion-content style="margin-top:44px;margin-bottom:44px;" overflow-scroll="false" scroll="true">
                     <ion-item class="row col item-list" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;" ng-repeat="item in category.items | orderBy: 'name' track by item.id">

                        <img ng-src="{{item.imagePath}}" class="col" style="height:{{height}}px;padding:0px;"></img>

                        <div class="gradient-image" style="height:{{height/2 + height/6}}px;position:absolute;width:100%;bottom:0px;margin-bottom:45px;">
                                <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;width:100%;margin-top:{{height/8}}px">
                                    <div>
                                        <p class="item-title">{{item.name | uppercase}}</p><br>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item-text-wrap">
                                        <p class="item-description">{{item.description}}</p><br>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row item action-panel padding" style="margin:0px;">

                            <div class="col action">
                                    <div class="info" style="text-align:center;font-size:20px;">{{::item.price | currency}}</div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col action">
                                <button ng-click="count = removeItem(item)" class="col button icon action" ng-class="{ 'minus-button': item.quantity > 0}" ng-disabled="item.quantity == 0">
                                <i class="icon ion-minus action action-icon" ng-if="item.quantity > 0"></i>
                                <i class="icon ion-minus action action-icon" style="color:#fff;" ng-if="item.quantity == 0"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col action">
                                <div class="info" ng-class="{'light':item.quantity == 0}" style="text-align:center;font-size:24px;" ng-model="item.quantity"><b>{{item.quantity}}</b></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col col-30">
                                <button ng-click="count = addItem(item)" class="col button icon primary-action">
                                    <i class="icon ion-plus primary-action-icon"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                     </ion-item>
                     </ion-content>
                 </ion-slide>
         </ion-slide-box>
```

Comment: This is essentially a bug report since you didn't include code. If there's something wrong on your end the only way to fix it is if we know your code, if it's something wrong on their end there's nothing we can do.

Comment: Why do you have so much custom styling on the ionic elements? For instance the position: absolute on the slide box? I find that these kind of alterations can have unintentional consequences like this.

Comment: I agree, my CSS skills are not something I am proud of...nonetheless..if you see something that stands out, let me know. It works perfectly fine in browser and iOS, just not android.